# Add consecutive number within each line

Tags: string, bash, awk

Assume a text file *file* that contains multiple lines of text strings.

```
> cat file
foo bar baz
bar quux foo
foo baz quux
```

I would like to add a consecutive number (with leading digits, followed by an underscore) to each third-column word.

```
> cat file | sought_command
foo bar 001_baz
bar quux 002_foo
foo baz 003_quux
```

I believe that this can be achieved simply via *awk* (`awk '{printf("%03d ...`), but can't come up with the proper code.

Comment: The second line of input and output don't match up

Comment: @123 You are right. My bad. I have corrected the above example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sprintf and assign it to $3, using the line number as the digit.

```
awk '$3=sprintf("%03d_%s",NR,$3)' file

foo bar 001_baz
bar baz 002_qux
foo baz 003_quux
```

Comment: `^1` but wish you'd gone with `{$3=sprintf("%03d_%s",NR,$3)}1` instead of just `$3=sprintf("%03d_%s",NR,$3)` so I wasn't wondering what condition you were trying to test for being true or false and then after convincing myself you were relying on it always being true having to think it through to see if there were any unexpected scenarios where $3 ends up numerically zero or null and so causing the condition to be false...

Comment: @EdMorton I considered that but it will always be true as NR will always be set, so there will always be output (and will return true) even if $3 was null/unset due to it being a string.

Comment: Right, that's the conclusion I eventually came to as well but IMHO it would've been better to not have to think about it. It's just 3 extra characters and then everyone KNOWS at a glance what the code will ALWAYS do, no pondering purpose and scenarios involved! It's kinda like quoting shell variables - sure there's times you don't NEED to do it but just do it anyway for clarity if nothing else.

Comment: @EdMorton I already thought about it before posting so anyone reading hopefully wouldn't have to. I do understand what you mean though and I do think clarity for the sake of a few characters is a always a good trade off, but in this case I just don't think it would add anything as it wasn't a requirement to print every line. Should every line be printed regardless, like if it did break somehow should the line still be printed even though the output would be incorrect?